# Qt: kill current process?

Tags: qt, process, kill

Is there a way in Qt to terminate a'la `TerminateProcess` the current process?

[QProcess::kill()](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qprocess.html) seem to be only applicable to other, external processes.

Comment: Does it really have to kill it? Is `QCoreApplication::exit()` not enough?

Comment: My guess is the QT folks haven't thought to wrap that.  You might have to code to the platform-specific APIs you're interested in.

Comment: @Lukas Yes, After the call I don't want to return to the event loop and I actually don't even want anything to be destroyed.

Comment: "I don't want to return to the event loop and I actually don't even want anything to be destroyed". Then just use abort(). :-)

Comment: `abort()` doesn't seem to be a function in any relevant class

Comment: abort() is a function in the c stdlib, not in Qt

Answer (score 4):

Here's my code for win/mac/linux, though not portable for other OSes.

```
void killMe()
{
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
  enum { ExitCode = 0 };
  ::TerminateProcess(::GetCurrentProcess(), ExitCode);
#else
  qint64 pid = QCoreApplication::applicationPid();
  QProcess::startDetached("kill -9 " + QString::number(pid));
#endif // Q_OS_WIN
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just call TerminateProcess directly, or if you want something platform independant: [exit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/exit)

Comment: TerminateProcess does what you want. Why do you need it wrapped in a Qt function?

Comment: platform independence obviously.

Comment: You should have made it clear that you needed a platform independent solution. As far as I know exit() is available on all platforms.

Comment: but `exit()` doesn't do what I want. `exit()` will still call static objects destructors before terminating.