# Killing a QProcess in Qt

Tags: qt, qprocess

I would like to know how to kill a `QProcess` in Qt, Linux. I start an external application say like an app that displays image (full screen), with no title bar, so no close button. Now I need to close this application say after 5 secs. How do I do that in Qt?

```
void MainWindow::Dialog()
{
  ......
  ......
  connect(pbLaunchImage,SIGNAL(released()),this, SLOT(launchImage()));
  //I am guessing a connect here to kill the started process
}

void MainWindow::launchImage()
{
    qWarning("Launching Image...");
    p->execute("/usr/bin/fancyImage");
}
```

**EDIT:**

> I still haven't figured it out but I found a workaround since I have the source of the external application. I added an Exit action which closes the opened external application. But if anyone has any idea about the QProcess please post it as an answer.

Comment: Like this?
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533200/qt-kill-current-process

Comment: QProcess::execute is a static method and will not do anything with `p`. What you want to call is p->start().

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I tried start but did not launch the app, until i used execute.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can not use [`QProcess::execute(...)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute), because it is a blocking convenience method. Your Qt program effectively stops (*bad* if it is a GUI program and it stops for more than an eye blink). You need to launch the process with [`QProcess::start(...)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start) and let your Qt program keep running.

---

If child process is well-behaved, simply call [QProcess::terminte() slot method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#terminate) to make it quit. The child process is sent TERM TERM signal (on Linux/Unix), and then it should cleanly exit.

If process is not well-behaved, and refuses to quit on TERM, you have to use [QProcess::kill() slot method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#kill), but I'd rather fix the child application if possible.

Then, to make it quit after 5 seconds, use a [`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html). So something like this in the place where you create `p`, assuming it is a *QProcess* and not something else:

```
// p = new QProcess... or something equivalent happened here
// below code needs to be done once per creation of `p`

// create a timer with p as parent, so it will be deleted properly
QTimer *killtimer = new QTimer(p); 
killtimer->setTimeout(5000); // 5 seconds
killtimer->setSingleShot(true); // should happen only once per process start

// make the timer's timeout to terminate the process
QObject::connect(killtimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), p, SLOT(terminate()));

// make the timer start when process starts
QObject::connect(p, SIGNAL(started()), killtimer, SLOT(start()));

// you also want to connect signals to slots, and at least do debug print
// example:
QObject::connect(p, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(handleStarted()));
QObject::connect(p, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(handleFinished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));
QObject::connect(p, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)), this, SLOT(handleError(QProcess::ProcessError)));

// then just launch the process. this program will also keep running
p->start("/usr/bin/fancyImage");
```

Comment: it did not work. I got these messages when I ran the app                  Cannot connect QTimer::timeout() to (null)::terminate()
Cannot connect (null)::started() to QTimer::start()

Comment: @XavierGeoffrey Well, isn't that a pretty clear message, when you look at the code? `p` is null. Edited the answer to clarify where the code above should go.

Comment: Sorry about that, i just overlooked. After the second connect, i am calling p->execute("someapp"); and after the timeout I don't see the event triggering and killing the process. The app is still running in the foreground. Any idea?

Comment: Uhm, sorry, should have noticed. You can't use [`execute`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute) for this. It is static method, and has nothing to do with `p` instance even if it is valid syntax to call it with `p->`. You need to use `start()` method. Will update answer later.

Comment: I did a workaround which accomplishes what I need for now. But I am still looking for the QProcess killing.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and let you know :)